# Advice on optimizing Table Structure

Tags: mysql, database

My table has 5 columns: `Date, Name, X, Y, Z`

For each Date there are ~10 Names. For each Name, there are around 1 million - 5 million records.

Queries *always* look like this:

`Select sum(Z) from TABLENAME where Name='somename' AND Date between 'somedate' and 'otherdate' group by X,Y`

For this small number of names, I simply partitioned the table on date; ignoring the extra expense of scanning over a large number of records in a date partition that we actually don't need to (since the query is ALWAYS for 1 `Name`, but over multiple (max 30) days)

**Now I need to scale this to ~600 `Name`s**, and it's obvious that continuing with the current model isn't feasable.

My first instinct was to SUBPARTITION for each `Name` within each `Date`. This should probably solve the problem of scale since MySQL would narrow it down to a single subpartition per date partition for whichever dates are in the `BETWEEN` clause.

**Is this a good solution? Is there something better I could do?** Because *creating* this sort of structure in an automated manner would be a pain; since I've to load data everyday, possibly with new `Name`s. So I'll have to introspect the CSV files I'm loading, create subpartitions in advance for each `Name` and then start `LOAD DATA INFILE`.

Comment: Show your database schema (its `CREATE TABLE` statements), including the indexes.

Comment: I don't have access to the server right now. There are no indexes/PKs on the table (there's no suitable column to index)